# mod_rewrite -> doesn't work as expected

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i use the following **.htaccess** to redirect all requests to my index.php except if a folder or file exists.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA]
```

But if i try url's like **domain.com/thing/a/thing/b** i get redirected to my index.php but everything else is messed up. The html doesn't link properly to the stylesheet and so on.

My application is working kinda like a MVC-Framework, i.e. everything happens over the index.php. So i don't want that other files are accessible except files in a public folder and some specific files. Namely cron.php in the root and some css/js/image files down the folder structure.

More details on the file structure: https://bitbucket.org/BrainInBlack/source-motd-plus/src

Or do i have to link stylesheets and other stuff with absolute paths, i.e. **"http://domain.com/path/to/style.css"** and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a slash client before `(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1`.

use this code:

```
RewriteRule ^/client(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1
```

Comment: URI's passed through `RewriteRule`'s inside htaccess files have the leading slash stripped off (since v2), that's never going to match anything from inside an htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to change all your links to absolute links or add a

```
<base href="http://domain.com/">
```

to the header of your pages.